# Is it really not necessary to filter the POST entries with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

In a complicated paging process with next/previous pages, 
I retrieve an additional filter to insert into my initial query filter.

```
Document filter = filter(...);
filter = Filters.and(filter, new Document(req.getParameter("paging")));
List results = MongoDb.aggregate(new Document("$match", filter),
                                            new Document("$limit", ...
```

"paging" is complete representation of a MongoDB filter ($and, $or ...) converted into a document.

Because I'm using $and I'm sure that the query will not get out of the first filter.

Please, is it really secure?

Comment: You need to show your full logic here, as it's unclear what your full code ( that we cannot see ) is actually doing. `$and` operators in particular are wildly misused in query operations and this is a large source of confusion and problems. All MongoDB operations are already AND conditions unless explicitly placed within an `$or` anyway. Show some more of how your code is building the queries so we can get a clear picture.